# c# read registry windows 8

Tags: c#, registry

I have an existing program, which demands for registry access using:

```
RegistryPermission permission = new RegistryPermission(RegistryPermissionAccess.AllAccess, strCheckPermission);
permission.Demand();
```

This works fine for Windows XP till Windows 7, and Windows Server 2003 and 2008. However, when I run this on Windows 8, when I demand this permission set, I still can't create a SubKey

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software", true).CreateSubKey("myCompany")
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong in here?

Update: a stacktrace of the exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Cannot write to the registry key.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.EnsureWriteable()
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistrySecurity registrySecurity)
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so please post full details.

Comment: The user must have the permission to access said registry hive.  I had no problem running your code on Windows 8.

Comment: To confirm what @Ramhound was saying, I can run this also on Windows 8 without issue. Try running Visual Studio as Administrator and debugging

Comment: I am running VS as Administrator, and yes I do have permission to add this key via Regedit.exe, but it still doesn't write the key...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up Code Access Security permissions with Windows rights.  CAS does not do anything to give you access to registry keys, it merely verifies that the permission wasn't disabled.  Which it rarely is, most .NET apps run in full trust.

This is a Window access right problem, your user account simply doesn't have the permission to write the key.  Which is not unusual, HKLM keys can only ever be written with UAC elevation.  You'll need to embed a manifest to ask for elevation, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-c-sharp-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7/2818776#2818776) for details.

A further Windows 8 specific detail is WinRT, a "Windows Store" app will never be able to write such keys, no workaround for that.

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you for your anser, this makes sense. I've turned UAC completely off, but Windows 8 still complains sometime about UAC (or "You have to be administrator to do this", although I am administrator. I guess that is related to this issue, so I'll try to solve that first. By the way, I'm using a ClickOnce application.

Comment: You cannot turn UAC off on Windows 8, it is used to implement sandboxing for Windows Store apps.  Nor is this anything you should ever try to do, your user's machine won't have it turned off.  A ClickOnce app should **never** mess with HKLM keys.

Comment: Maybe I can't turn UAC completely off, but I've turned UAC to "Never notify me when...". I cannot work with UAC turned on - it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Peter, I'm having the same problem. A .NET app that was able to create & write to a registry key when I ran it elevated in windows 7 will no longer let me in Windows 8. I finally gave in and manually did it for now. I'm trying this from the deployed app, not from Visual Studio. Have you found a solution? Thanks

Comment: same issue here. my manifest successfully requests elevated permissions. I write and read the reg value, but seems that I cannt see the settings when working in regedit.

Comment: @boom - If you don't get an exception then you have another problem.  Typically it is registry redirection, getting redirected to the Wow6432Node key because your program is running in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit operating system.  Change the platform target to AnyCPU or use the RegistryView enum.

Comment: Ah. Im running inside visual studio, so I bet it's forcing to 32 bit. Thanks!